# Unable to use X11 Forwarding between Windows (WSL) and Linux

Tags: ssh, x11, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having issues with X11 forwarding between a Windows 10 system using [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq) and a Ubuntu 19 system. To clarify, I am wanting to connect *to* the Ubuntu server (LNX) *from* the Windows 10 system (WIN). Once I do this, I am ultimately wanting to be able to run `<command> | xclip -selection clipboard` on LNX, and have that output copied to the clipboard of WIN.

On WIN, I have XLaunch/Xming running with the display number set to `:0`. *I can launch local Linux applications such as xterm and xclock without issues*.

On LNX, I have `X11Forwarding` set to yes.

From WIN, I connect to LNX using X11 forwarding (-X). I don't believe this to be an actual issue, but figured I would mention, that when I log in I do get this even though I still successfully login:

```
WIN-$ ssh -X LNX
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

Once I am connected to LNX using X11 forwarding, I run the following command and get this error:

```
LNX-$ ls -a | xc
connect localhost port 6010: Connection refused
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Obviously after that point, the data being copied via xclip from LNX is not being copied to WIN.

I'm not quite sure why it's attempting to open `localhost:10.0`. And I've tried using a variety of display names and numbers with no success. I'm simply wanting to copy data via xclip over SSH from LNX to WIN.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can only answer one of your sub-questions: "I'm not quite sure why it's attempting to open `localhost:10.0`" -- the display is mapped to a different display number (`:0`) will probably be in use.

Comment: "localhost:10.0" is the expected value of DISPLAY for a forwarded X session, and it normally maps to TCP port 6010 (6000 + 10). On the remote system, try running "netstat -anp | grep 6010" to see if anything is actually listening on port 6010.

Comment: Hi @Kenster it does look like there is a process actively listening on 6010. But it doesn't specify the PID/Program Name in the output. `tcp  0  0  127.0.0.1:6010  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  -`

Comment: "Connection refused" normally means nothing is listening for connections on the requested address/port. If you have something listening on 127.0.0.1:6010, then I don't know why you would get that error. Maybe "localhost" isn't resolving to 127.0.0.1 for some reason? Or maybe some firewall software on the linux system is interfering?

Comment: What is the IP-address for the windows host ? If the X server host has 192.168.2.30 as it's IP-address,  what happends if you do this:  "DISPLAY=192.16.2.30:0 /usr/bin/xterm"  ? This should work as long as you don't something like NAT/PAT in between (the windows hosts needs to be directly reachable from LNX) or some firewall's blocks the connection.